# Copy and paste special

Tags: excel, vb.net, excel-interop

I have data of text and images in one excel (say "excel 1"), I want to copy all (means: text,images, page brake view, column width and rows height) and paste into another excel(say "excel 2").. SO how this is done.

please look at the code

```
xlsheet1 = xlWb1.Sheets("Sheet1")
xlsheet1.Range("A1:Q132").Copy()

Try

    xlsheet2.Range("A1").PasteSpecial(Excel.XlPasteType.xlPasteValues, False, False) ''Paste special Format:=

Catch ex As Exception
      MsgBox(ex.ToString)
End Try
```

my Result:

Only Text is pasting nothing else

Comment: Do you want to copy data from one sheet into another sheet, or to another file?

Comment: Please show a more complete code sample. I am unable to execute this because it shows an `PasteSpecial method of Range class failed` error on the line with `PasteSpecial`.